# En SQLite cómo unir tablas con excepciones

Tags: sqlite, join

Buen día a todos, mi pregunta es la siguiente, supongamos que tengo las dos tablas siguientes:

tabla1
id1   id2   dato1   dato2
----   ----   -------    -------
1      a      d1a1    d2a1
1      b      d1b1    d2b1
2      a      d1a2    d2a2
2      b      d1a2    d2a2
3      a      d1a3    d2a3
3      c      d1c3    d2c3

tabla2
id1   id2   dato3   dato4
----   ----   -------    -------
1      a      d3a1    d4a1
null  b      d3b1    d4b1
null  a      d3a2    d4a2
2      b      d3a2    d4a2

y quiero unirlas haciendo:

SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM tabla1 t1 JOIN tabla2 t2 ON t1.id1 = t2.id2 AND t1.id2 = t2.id2

Esto me va a devolver la siguiente tabla:

id1   id2   dato1   dato2   dato3   dato4
----   ----   -------    -------   --------   --------
1      a      d1a1    d2a1    d3a1    d4a1
2      b      d1b2    d2b2    d3b2    d4b2

Qué debería hacer para obtener como resultado la siguiente tabla:

id1   id2   dato1   dato2   dato3   dato4
----   ----   -------    -------   --------   --------
1      a      d1a1    d2a1    d3a1    d4a1
null  b      null       null      d3b2    d4b2
null  a      null       null      d3a2    d4a2
2      b      d1b2    d2b2    d3b2    d4b2

Comment: Me dice que tanto el right join como el full outer join no están soportados

Comment: tenes razon.. inverti las tablas y usa un left join...

Comment: Tampoco, invertí las tablas y no me toma los null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto funciona con un left join (ya que sqlite no soporta rigth join)

La siguiente query, funciona:

```
select * 
from tabla2 t2 left join tabla1 t1 on t1.id1= t2.id1 and t1.id2 = t2.id2
```

Left join trae todos los registros de la tabla que esta a la izquierda (la primera) aunque no cumplan la condición de join. No trae los que no cumplen que estan a la derecha (la segunda)

Y [aca](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/48aea/3/0) un fiddle de ejemplo.

Comment: muchas gracias, no me estaba funcionando porque en mi solicitud real estaba agregando unas condiciones que no iban. Muchas gracias!